# Unsubscribe issue affecting 4% of users

Tags: mobile, unsubscribe

A significant minority of users are getting uncaught exceptions when they try to unsubscribe, "Missing Parameters".

I suspect it's to do with cookies and sessions.

We use a 3rd party SMTP gateway service (Mandrill) which munges email we send by intercepting all link URLs and changing them to its own tracking URLs.

This means CiviCRM's unsubscribe URLs get changed from `https://example.org/civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe?xxxx` to `https://3rdpartytracker.com/yyy`.

Fetching the 3rd party URL results in a 301 redirect to the original URL. This is how all link trackers work, so no surprises there.

However, I've noticed, thanks to the [report error extension](https://github.com/mlutfy/reporterror/) sending me the POSTed data, that *somehow* CiviCRM has managed to set the hidden `entryURL` field to the original 3rd party redirect URL, when I think it should be its own.

`entryURL` is only set in one or two places in the codebase, so I put some checks in that would log something if it was being set to something other than the `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`, i.e. it should trigger if it was setting the `entryURL` to the third party. This code never triggered though.

I think it's always on mobile, but then it's a mix of Chrome 80 on Android 10, iPhone Safari 13.1 on iOS 13.5, iPhone Safari 12.1 on iOS 12.4.

Could it be some weird reverse proxy thing (where the 301 is handled up the chain instead of the client device)? Could it be some weird pre-fetch of links optimisation? I'm a bit stumped.

I'm on CiviCRM 5.24.5, Drupal 7.